# how to use flask-ask without using ngrok

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

okay so I'm really inexperienced with all this so bear with me if this is a dumb question.

So I'm planning out a raspberry pi that can turn my computer off and on with alexa commands. So far the best candidate I've found so far is flask-ask. My only issue with it is that it seems to rely on ngrok, and since I want to have this as a permanent part of my computer, I would have to buy at least the basic tier so I could have a static url. I would rather not do this as 60 dollars a year is a bit more than I am willing to pay for something like this. What I want to know is if and how I can use flask-ask with ngrok alternatives like localtunnel or something else along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa to deploy your flask-ask application.

Tutorial available here : [AWS Alexa deploy on aws lambda using zappa](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/8e8ad73a-99e9-4c0f-a7b3-60f92287b0bf/new-alexa-tutorial-deploy-flask-ask-skills-to-aws-lambda-with-zappa)